# Check for undefined variable with part of it's name being a variable, in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery snippet which sets the 'selectedIndex' property of six select elements to '0'.

```
for (m = 1; m <= 6; m++)                                    {
        $("#po"+eval("leafWId"+m)).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
    }
```

In the snippet scope there are among others the following variables defined:
 leafWId1,  leafWId2,  leafWId3,  leafWId4 with each one of these set to a different number, so the part

```
eval("leafWId"+m)
```

in each iteration, is equivalent to

```
eval("leafWId1"), eval("leafWId2"), eval("leafWId3")........
```

and thus, evaluates to each of the numbers referred above, and the snippet

```
$("#po"+eval("leafWId"+m))
```

returns a jQuery object consisting of select elements with id value of the type: "po345" for example.

Now, when the 'm' variable is set through the iteration to value '5', I get an Uncaught Reference Error, reporting that "leafWId5 is not defined" (as expected, since only four variables are defined, ie, leafWId1,  leafWId2,  leafWId3,  leafWId4 as mentioned above).

I want to add a conditional statement that will check for an undefined variable whose name will be the result of the evaluation

```
eval("leafWId"+m)
```

and if is defined, then use the prop() method, if not, skip this, so I dont' get the Reference Error.

Or as an alternative, maybe check for the length of the jQuery object below

```
$("#po"+eval("leafWId"+m))
```

and proceed with the prop() method only when it's length is greater than zero.

Actually, the problem I face is that when m variable is set to '5', the part

```
  eval("leafWId"+m)
```

evaluates to 'leafWId5', a variable that is not defined, and the snippet does not let me check for 'undefined' value in advance, because the eval() function gives an error, so any conditional statement I have used that checks for existing variable and uses the eval() function does not work.

Comment: do not use eval() for string concatenation. So you have a variable `leafWId0` and you want to use that?

Comment: Please never, ever, *ever* use `eval()`. An object with keys that you access via bracket notation is a much better alternative. Better still use an array you access by index.

Comment: @epascarello - Not being used for concatenation here, being used to look up runtime-defined variable names.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, there *are* some legitimate use cases for `eval`, but the general rule is that if you think you need to use `eval`, you probably don't.

Comment: try {
eval(leafWId75)
} catch (e) {
console.log('no reference error');
continue;
}

Comment: first a fall dont ever go with eval, but if you wanna proceed and proceed further only when the html element exists then you can wrap the statement inside a conditional IF statement as, `if ( $(“#po”+eval(“leafWid”+m)) ) { write your statement }`